# Clojure - Append Collection is not working

Tags: react-native, clojurescript, cljsrn

I have a feature of uploading images. There is a gallery of images and I need to update the gallery on adding new photos. The photo upload is success, but, the UI is not getting updated with the newly added photo.

I am using entitydb for storing the list locally.

My controller method is below:

```
:post-art (pipeline! [value app-db] 
                  (when value
                    (pipeline! [value app-db]
                      (post-art-photo app-db value)
                      (let [res (:createArtPicture value)]
                        (pp/commit! (edb/append-collection app-db :artPicture :list [(assoc res :art {:id (:artId res)})])) 
                        (pp/commit! (assoc-in app-db [:kv :art-pictures-list] (edb/get-collection app-db :artPicture :list)))
                        (pp/commit! (assoc-in app-db [:kv :temp-photo] nil))
                        (navigate-go! {:key "art-single" :id (:artId res)}))
                      (rescue! [error]
                        nil))))
```

entitydb schema is:

```
(def edb-schema
  {:art         {:id        :id
                 :relations {:photos     [:many :asset]
                             :authors    [:many :author]
                             :campus     [:one :campus]
                             :thumbnail  [:one :asset]
                             :categories [:many :artCategory]}}
   :author      {:id        :id 
                 :relations {:avatar [:one :asset]
                             :arts   [:many :art]}}
   :campus      {:id        :id
                 :relations {:arts  [:many :art]
                             :photo [:one :asset]}}
   :artCategory {:id        :id
                 :relations {:icon [:one :asset]
                             :arts [:many :art]}}
   :artList     {:id        :id
                 :relations {:user [:one :user]
                             :state [:many :art]}}
   :artPicture {:id        :id
                :relations {:user [:one :user]
                            :art [:one :art]}
                :middleware {:set [(fn [a]
                                      (assoc a :art {:id (:artId a)}))]}}
   :comment     {:id        :id
                 :relations {:user [:one :user]
                             :art [:one :art]}
                 :middleware {:set [(fn [a]
                                       (assoc a :art {:id (:artId a)}))]}}
   :favorite    {:id        :id
                 :relations {:user [:one :user]}}
   :game        {:id        :id
                 :relations {:user [:one :user]}}
   :user        {:id        :id
                 :relations {:artLists    [:many :artList]
                             :artPictures [:many :artPicture]
                             :comments    [:many :comment]
                             :favorites   [:many :favorite]
                             :games       [:many :game]}}
   :asset       {:id :id}})
```

The issue is with 'artPicture'. The 'comment' also have the same feature. But, that is working fine. Anyone, please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. I have wrapped the code inside a "pipeline! [value app-db]" and that worked!

```
:post-art-picture (pipeline! [value app-db] 
                    (when value
                      (pipeline! [value app-db]
                        (post-art-photo app-db value)
                        (let [res (:createArtPicture value)]
                          (pipeline! [value app-db]
                            (pp/commit! (edb/append-collection app-db :artPicture :list [(assoc res :art {:id (:artId res)})])) 
                            (pp/commit! (assoc-in app-db [:kv :temp-photo] nil))
                            (navigate-replace! (-> (util/current-route (get-in app-db [:route]))
                                          (dissoc :subpage)
                                          (assoc :subpage "completed")))
                            (rescue! [error]
                            (util/log "Photo Upload ERROR:" error)))))))
```